What is Lie integration?
Lie integration as far as I understand is a smooth simplicial presheaf with a graded Leibniz rule
$$\textrm{LieAlg} \rightarrow \textrm{ dgcAlg  }^{\textrm{op}}$$
this integration is the parallel transport of A
If the cohomology in question is deRham cohomology, then it is ordinary integration of differential forms

What is a good reference to find the definition and perhaps some of the properties of Lie integration?

Maybe it's just me, but I don't see an actual question here. :-/

The nLab article has a lot of references: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lie+integration

I’m voting to close this question because it seems to have been generated by copy-pasting text without formulating a proper question
